# How to add an additional parameter to an exiting array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In my script I query a MySQL database and add results to an array.

```
$result = mysqli_query($ssdbc,$q);
$rows = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

     $rows[] = $row; 
   }
```

This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [systName] => ahu17s
    [x] => 499
    [y] => 133
)
Array
(
    [systName] => 11zktl
    [x] => 667
    [y] => 280
)
Array
(
    [systName] => zy12px
    [x] => 485
    [y] => 111
)
```

**So, how do I add an additional key to each array**, so that, after the edit, each array-item would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [systName] => ahu17s
    [x] => 499
    [y] => 133
    [NEW_KEY] => SOME_VALUE
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: update `$row` before inserting into `$rows[]` .. like `$row['newkey'] = 'new value'`

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysqli_query($ssdbc,$q);
$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $row["foo"] = "bar";
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Maybe something like this ? Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($ssdbc,$q);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $row['NEW_KEY'] = 'SOME_VALUE';
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```